# Series of functions $\log(1+x^{2n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Does the series of functions $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \log(1+x^{2n})$ converges for $|x|<1$?
Obviously I've observed that for $x=0$ the series is convergent and for $x\ge1$ is divergent.
How should I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say that it diverges when $x>0$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $x\ge 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the series of functions
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \log(1+x^{2n})
$$
you're interested in its convergence for $|x| < 1$. You've already observed the behavior at $x = 0$ and $x \geq 1$, which is a good start.

To study its convergence for $|x| < 1$, let's use the properties of the logarithm and the fact that the domain in question does not contain any non-positive integers.

Since $\log(1 + t) < t$ for $t > 0$ (you can see this from the series expansion of the logarithm or by considering the graph of $y = \log(1+t)$ and $y = t$), we can say:
$$
\log(1 + x^{2n}) < x^{2n}
$$

Now, consider the sum of the right-hand side:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^{2n}
$$
This is a geometric series with ratio $x^2$. Since $|x| < 1$, $|x^2| < 1$ as well, so this series converges (to $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$).

By the comparison test, if $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^{2n}$ converges and $0 \leq \log(1+x^{2n}) < x^{2n}$ for all $n$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \log(1+x^{2n})$ also converges for $|x| < 1$.

Hence, the given series converges for all $|x| < 1$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the question is: the convergence you've proved is pointwise, right? It's also uniform on every subset $[a,b]\subset(-1,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes. The convergence I demonstrated was pointwise for \( |x| < 1 \). For uniform convergence on subsets \([a,b] \subset (-1,1)\), you'd typically employ the Weierstrass M-test. Given our earlier inequalities, for any \( x \) in \([a,b]\), the terms \( x^{2n} \) will have a maximum on this interval due to the compactness of \([a,b]\). By showing the series of these maxima converges, we can then establish uniform convergence on the subset. Thus, the series does indeed converge uniformly on every \([a,b] \subset (-1,1)\).